# Using "exec" to Update a Table

Tags: sql-server, exec, temp-tables

I have a temp table named as `#temp` with 2 columns:

```
clientID (varchar), 
result (int)
```

I just want to loop in it and check the clientID with a stored procedure which takes 2 varchar parameters and returns 0 or 1.

I coded:

```
update #temp set result=exec sp_x 'clientID' '@clientID'
```

`clientID` is the column name of `#temp`.
`@clientID` comes from parameter of the main SP

It comes up with a warning:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.

So, what to do?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't use a stored procedure as the value for an update statement. And honestly if your stored procedure is returning a value like that you are doing it wrong. The return from a procedure is intended to indicate a status of the execution, not return a value. If you want a value returned you should use an output parameter. I have a feeling this whole process can be greatly improved by modifying that procedure and getting rid of the loop entirely. If you can post some more details I will help you figure it out.

Comment: This is th SP i call:
`create procedure [dbo].sp_CrossCheck2 (@clientID varchar(16), @mainID varchar(16))
AS
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @sqlMain nvarchar(max);
declare @Params nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'select @sqlMainOUT = sql from sql where clientID='+@clientID
SET @Params = N'@sqlMainOUT nvarchar(max) OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @Params, @sqlMainOUT=@sqlMain OUTPUT;

create table #temp (clientID varchar(16), result int default 0)

insert into #temp exec sp_executesql @sqlMain

if (@mainID in (select clientID from #temp)) select 1 else select 0`

Comment: Sorry for the format. I am kinda newbie. When i execute this SP in the query it comes with a result of 0 or 1. So what do u think? Thanks in advance....

Comment: You should take a look at this article since you are naming your procedures with the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your procedure inside a loop

```
declare @id varchar(10)
declare @result int
declare looper cursor for select clientID, result from #temp

fetch next from looper
into @id, @result

-- loop on #temp table
open looper
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  -- call your procedure and store the result into a variable
  -- do what ever you need to do

end

close looper
deallocate looper
```

Comment: Thanks FLICKER. Those codes are very new to me. I just want to understand that: u didnt mention about #temp here. So will the looper detect the clientID and result of #temp, or how will be? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, right. I missed it. Please see the code, I edited.